# How to use Microsoft Word formula IF statement to output text

Tags: ms-word

I am currently trying to produce a text value in R3C2 by inserting a function (in the cell R3C2) with the syntax (all values within the formula are produced in the same table):

```
=IF(R1C2<R2C2,"Pass,"Fail")
```

However, this gives me a syntax error.

Is there a something obvious I am missing (i.e. formulas do not produce text)?

Do I need to use more sophisticated methods (i.e. VBA)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit more complicated in Word than in Excel
`{IF {=B1} < {=B2} "Pass" "Fail"}`

You have to use Ctrl + F9 to get the curly brackets!!!

Cells have to be referenced by `A1` notation.

No comma to separate single parts.

No option to drag down!!!

Comment: Thanks! One super small point. After I press Alt + F9 to hide the formatting, how do I "run" the code? The spot was blank until I print previewed it (for example).

Comment: You update the formula via context menu

Comment: Going to try my luck with a bonus question. Can I use the same syntax for Bookmarks (i.e. values from other tables)?

Comment: yes, that should work.